# The model subclass of RLMObject doesn't have any NSArray property but still getting the RLMArray exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I am trying to use Realm as my mobile database inside the app. So I subclased my model class from RLMObject and while compiling the code I am getting this error. I don't have any clue why this is happening since I don't have any NSArray property inside my model class :-(

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'RLMArray properties require a protocol defining the contained type - example: RLMArray<Person>.'
```

Edit :- Sample Code

```
@interface GSShow : RLMObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber<RLMInt>     *showId;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber<RLMInt>     *numberOfTimesRated;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString       *trailerUrl;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString       *backdropUrl;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString       *posterUrl;
@end
```

The important thing is here is I haven't write any usages of Realm Api's yet in my code.

Error Logs :-

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'RLMArray properties require a protocol defining the contained type - example: RLMArray<Person>.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001083c6d85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010a0bbdeb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   Realm                               0x000000010957ec85 -[RLMProperty setTypeFromRawType] + 1813
    3   Realm                               0x000000010957fd32 -[RLMProperty initWithName:indexed:property:] + 322
    4   Realm                               0x000000010955edd5 +[RLMObjectSchema propertiesForClass:isSwift:] + 1461
    5   Realm                               0x000000010955cf79 +[RLMObjectSchema schemaForObjectClass:] + 809
    6   Realm                               0x0000000109656e7f +[RLMSchema registerClasses:count:] + 1663
    7   Realm                               0x0000000109659725 _ZZ25+[RLMSchema sharedSchema]ENK3$_0clEv + 517
    8   Realm                               0x000000010965950b _ZNSt3__117__call_once_proxyINS_5tupleIJOZ25+[RLMSchema sharedSchema]E3$_0EEEEEvPv + 91
    9   libc++.1.dylib                      0x0000000107d0310b _ZNSt3__111__call_onceERVmPvPFvS2_E + 117
    10  Realm                               0x000000010965756c +[RLMSchema sharedSchema] + 524
    11  Realm                               0x000000010955932b +[RLMObjectBase sharedSchema] + 43
    12  Realm                               0x0000000109556b1b _ZL26RLMInitializedObjectSchemaP13RLMObjectBase + 123
    13  Realm                               0x0000000109556a43 -[RLMObjectBase init] + 115
    14  Realm                               0x000000010955487b -[RLMObject init] + 59
    15  Goodshows                           0x000000010749d635 -[GSShow initWithAttributes:] + 85
```

Comment: can you show more detailed error, line, file where it is pointing to?

Comment: @ogres I posted the top part of error logs.

Comment: you've posted the wrong model. Please post all of your Realm models. Really, we just need the one with an `RLMArray` property missing its containing type, but please post all of them to be safe.

Comment: @jpsim yeah got it. Thanks! I was looking into this model only because the logs pointing to that only.